# want to insert data using jquery ajax and php

Tags: jquery, ajax, insert

I'm not able insert data into database using this code. My PHP code is correct.
What am I doing wrong?

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  $("#submit").click(function() {

    $.ajax({
      url: "q&a.php",
      success: function(result) {
        $("#users-cm").html(result);
      }
    });

  });

});
```

Comment: What data? You have to send data and you haven't defined any. Strongly suggest you read the `$.ajax` documentation and study some tutorials

Comment: For reference, see [jQuery.ajax()](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/). There are some [examples](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/#entry-examples) near the bottom of the page.

Comment: i am carrying data through session variable in q&a.php , is that data work in ajax.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

your code should be like:

```
 $.ajax({
  method: "POST",
   url: "q&a.php",
  data: { name: "John", location: "Boston" } //data which you want to send as form data
})
  .done(function( msg ) { //callback function
    alert( "Data Saved: " + msg );
  });
```

Hope this will give you an Idea, enjoy

Comment: is this code correct ???  $(function(){                           
    $("#submit").click(function(){
  
  var comments = $("#txtarea").val();
  var datastring = "txtarea="+comments;
        $.ajax({
   type: "POST",
   url: "q&a.php", 
   cache: false,
   data: datastring,
   success: function(result){
            $("#users-cm").html(result);
        }});
    });
});

Comment: i am carrying data through session variable in q&a.php , is that data work in ajax.

Comment: can you please post your PHP code where you are handling this data?

Comment: i have tried php code without ajax ,that is working.

Comment: if($_SESSION['logged'] == "true" && isset($_SESSION['email']) && isset($_SESSION['userid']))$question = "";  if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == "POST"){if(empty($_POST['question'])){$error = "empty field";}else{
$question = $ObjectTestData->test_input($_POST['question']);}

Comment: remaining part of previous code.       if(!empty($question)){ $queryForAsk = "INSERT INTO ask (college_id, userid, email, question, qtime) VALUES('$ccd', '$uud', '$em', '$question',NOW())"; $resultForAsk = mysqli_query($connect, $queryForAsk);} }}